# Spring project release process

Tags: java, spring, release

Could someone help me understand how the release process for [Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) project works, as far as I can see in the project, the final artifacts of different modules of this project are released on some predefined interval. Does it mean that all the modules will be released with the same release version at those interval even if there is no changes in an specific module? what about bug fixes? Do they have new release for all the modules even if they are fixing a bug for a specific module?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no predefined interval (although it might seem like it) I think they strive to once a month. They release when they think it needs to be released. If there is nothing to release there will be no release. And yes all modules will be released and you should always use the same version for all modules and don't mix versions.